# How can I fix my dynamic progress bar so I can make a customisable length for it and it still fills the bar with the correct amount of characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't make the bar fill up with the symbol one by one. I mean it is fills up, but it is puts 2 or 3 (depends on the current percentage) symbols at once, and when it counts up to another 10% it puts 2-3 symbols again until 100%

I tried everything in my knowledge (I just started programming a few weeks ago), but the only way I can make it to fill up one by one is that I take the length of the bar and iterate through it. Thats not what I want because then the percentage depends on how many list elements are filled up. And thats not good because I dont want to make a 100 characters long list just to count up the 'percentage' one by one, and not every 5%.

for example: Last time I made a 20 character long list that means when the last element is filled up it is 100% but in this case I have to add +5 to the count variable each loop. but if I want it to make to a 10 char long list and after 1 loop it adds 5 to the count variable then the max 'percent' that I got is 50.

```
from time import sleep


def bar(blen):

    progress = []

    for p in range(blen):
        progress.append(' ')

    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        sleep(0.1)
        for i in progress:
            indx = progress.index(i)
            if count == 10:
                percent = (blen * 10) // 100
                for m in range(percent + 1):
                    progress[m] = '■'

            elif count == 20:
                percent = (blen * 20) // 100
                for m in range(percent + 1):
                    progress[m] = '■'

            elif count == 30:
                percent = (blen * 30) // 100
                for m in range(percent + 1):
                    progress[m] = '■'

        print(''.join(progress), count, end='\r')

        if count >= 100:
            break


bar(19)
```

So in this code above I got it right, that after every 10% it fills up the right amount, after passing every 10%, but I want it to fill up one by one depending on the % of the count variable. And if I make it 5 a character long list I still want it to count up to 100% and fill up at the correct speed at the same time.

I dont want to import a module that already have a fully working progress bar, I want to make my own, but sadly ran into a dead end with the percentages :D

I dont know if you can understand my problem but this is the best way I can explain it AND sorry for my bad grammar, my main language is not english.

Comment: if you have 20 elements then you should add square every `100/20 = 5` percent. If you have 10 elements then add square every `100/10 = 10` percent. If you have N elements then every `100/N` percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 20 elements then you should add square every `100/20 = 5` percent. If you have 10 elements then add square every `100/10 = 10` percent. If you have `N` elements then every `100/N` percent. And then number of squares is `count/(100/N)`

To make it looks better you can even use `99/N` as step.

I print `'123456789012345678901234567890'` to easily check how many suqares it printed.

```
from time import sleep

def bar(blen):
    step = 99/blen
    for count in range(101):
        sleep(0.1)
        a = int(count/step)
        b = blen-a
        print('■'*a, end='')
        print(' '*b, end='')
        print(count, end='\r')

print('123456789012345678901234567890')
bar(20)
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much, this is what I'm looking for. Looks like I still have a lot of things to learn :D